# Uninstall of jre 1.8 windows 7 in wrong way - now all .exe files open as binary in text editor

Tags: java, windows, spring

I cannot open any programs ending with .exe, not even the command line because all files with .exe extension are opening as binary in a text editor. I am on a 64-bit machine running windows 7.  Prior to this issue I already had:

jdk's 1.7 and 1.6 installed, with the windows java environment set to use JRE 1.7 (setting through control panel -> java -> java tab).

Steps that created the issue:

- Program needed JRE 1.8 to run/launch. So following Oracle/Java prompts I installed JRE 1.8.
- LCompleted the activity I was doing.
- Went to launch Spring Tool Suite to do development
- Spring would not launch because it is configured to use 1.6
- Went to programs/java/jre1.8 folder & deleted it to see if it would then pick up jdk 1.6 instead.
- This did not work. Checked java -version from command line, & it listed 1.8
- Went to Control panel -> java ->java tab & deleted 1.8 line from available JRE's/JDKs, & had only 1.7 present
- Went back to command line after logging out/in so changes would be registered by the machine, & "java -version" still said 1.8
- Made mistake of then, with programs/java/jre1.8 folder still in trash, of going to control panel -> programs and features -> java 8 entry & hitting uninstall.

I can't even open a command line or a web browser on that machine. Anyone know steps to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Open an administrative command prompt and use the command "assoc .exe=exefile". That should restore your .exe file association. If you can't open your command line through regular means, try opening task manager and selecting File -> New Task -> cmd

Comment: When I go to task manager -> file _ new Task -> cmd it launches as  binary in my text editor.

Comment: Try getting the default exe registry association from this site: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html . You should be able to put it on a thumb drive or something like that, and then you can use task manager File->New Task->Default_EXE.reg.

Comment: Try making a copy of cmd.exe and renaming it cmd.com.